# graphql-modules not calling __resolveType

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm not entirely sure about the purpose / action of `__resolveType` function on an interface / union, but I suppose it's adding a `__typename` field with the resolved type. However, I cannot seem to get this working with `graphql-modules`. Here as subset, but sufficient subset of my schema.

```
const typeDefs = gql`
interface Node {
    id: ID!
}

type User implements Node {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    password: String
}

type Group implements Node {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

type Query {
    node(id: ID!): Node
}`;
```

And my resolver down below.

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        node: () => {
            return { id: 'abc', email: 'a@b.c', password: 'test' };
        }
    },
    Node: {
        __resolveType: () => {
            console.log('__resolveType');
            return 'User';
        }
    }
}
```

Which together combine to a module.

```
const Module = new GraphQLModule({
    resolvers,
    typeDefs,
});
```

Used with Apollo server like.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    modules: [Module],
})

// Launch etc...
```

But when querying for `node` the __resolveType doesn't get logged and i get the following error.

> Abstract type Node must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.node with { id: "abc", email: "a@b.c" password: "test" }, received "undefined". Either the Node type should provide a "resolveType" function or each possible type should provide an "isTypeOf" function."

What am I doing wrong, and how would I solve this problem?

Quick note: adding `__typename: 'User'` in the returned object in `Query.node` seems to work, but doesn't seem like the ideal solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the same issue, can confirm that it appears __resolveType is never called when using graphql-modules. I'm going to raise an issue in the repo and reference this SO. Will post back any answer I get.

It has already been reported in the repo issues and the fix was to pass the toplevel module schema to apollo-server, not as modules

```
({
    schema: Appmodule.schema,
    context: session => session
})
```

see issue here. https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-modules/issues/619

Can confirm this is working